# PHP - Write to file isn't working

Tags: php, html

I am trying to develop a website which uses PHP to write to a text file. I have made a text document called 'newfile.txt' at the right file path and I have run the code in Google Chrome. The file just isn't written to and I can't find any code online which is different to mine. It does not produce an error message either. What have I done wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$myfile = fopen("C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unableto open file!");
$txt = "John Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Jane Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But, are you looking for errors? [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)
[`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\` character in PHP is like C, C++, Java, where it denotes an escape, like in `\n`.  So to denote a literal `\` you must either:

(1) Double it: `\\`
(2) (For file paths) Reverse it: `/`

So either:

```
fopen("C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Documents\\newfile.txt", "w")
```

or

```
fopen("C:/Users/Andrew/Documents/newfile.txt", "w")
```

or....
 use single quotes (which in PHP don't process escape sequences)

```
fopen('C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\newfile.txt', "w")
```

Comment: Or use single quotes, which don't process escape sequences.